# Highcharts render bug with logarithmic scale

Tags: highcharts

I have  a stacked bar chart witch is not rendered properly on large screens: [image]. While it works on normal screen sizes the bars magically disappears when the screen gets really wide with this stacktrace:

```
Error: Invalid value for <text> attribute x="-Infinity"a.xSetter 
@ highcharts.js:78O.attr 
@ highcharts.js:44Va.render 
@ highcharts.js:114(anonymous function) 
@ highcharts.js:153o 
@ highcharts.js:25ka.render 
@ highcharts.js:153ka.redraw 
@ highcharts.js:155(anonymous function) 
@ highcharts.js:213o 
@ highcharts.js:25hb.redraw 
@ highcharts.js:213hb.setSize 
@ highcharts.js:224(anonymous function) 
@ highcharts.js:222setTimeout (async)Pa 
@ highcharts.js:10hb.reflow 
@ highcharts.js:222b 
@ highcharts.js:222
```

Note that its works when its not yAxis type is not set to `logarithmic`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrjq4s50/1/):

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },

        yAxis: {
            type: 'logarithmic',
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{"data":[2,2,3,3,4,4,3,3,66,65],"name":"T1","stack":"purchases","color":"#a3f5c4","enableMouseTracking":true},{"data":[4,4,6,6,9,9,7,8,181,189],"name":"T2","stack":"offers","color":"#f5d4a3","enableMouseTracking":false},{"data":[17,7,14,19,16,14,19,23,473,460],"name":"T#","stack":"paywalled","color":"#f5a3a3","enableMouseTracking":false}]
    });
});
```

Comment: How big my screen needs to be? 1900px+ works fine. Issue sounds like trying to calculate logarithmic value for 0. Have you tried to set `yAxis.min = 1` ?

Comment: Happens on a `2560 x 1440` in full screen mode, but you can also just decrease the font size. Its also not a specific max width. It just stops working on a size but if you make the screen wider it starts to work again. I don't think it has to to with log of `0`, the example has no `0` values

Comment: Just tried `yAxis.min = 1` but it does not fix it.

Comment: Right! That size was a crucial part. Reported as bug here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5076 - thanks! Meanwhile, please try my workaround.